# Li contents are rendered outside ul container border

Tags: html, css

In this JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9qyv03u3/

It looks like this:

[image]

```css
ul {
    width: 20em;
    border: 4px solid gray;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    margin: 5em auto;
    list-style: None;
    height: 30px;
}
li {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 30px 10px 0;
    border-right-style: dotted;
    padding-right : 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Questions</li>
    <li>Tags</li>
    <li>Users</li>
</ul>
```

I am able to bring the contents inside box by giving `ul {height: 40px;}` but still the space above menu items are much larger than the space below.

How can I place the menu items inside `ul` container's center?

Comment: It works for me in chrome and IE 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you see the items out of box is because the height collapsing on the container, learn more [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html). as a quick fix you could simply set `ul{overflow:auto;}`.

But I suggest to use `display:inline-block` on the `li` rather than `float`, set same amount of top and bottom `padding`, remove `height`, and add `text-align:center` on the `ul`. That will make sure the items centered in both ways.

```css
ul {
    width: 20em;
    border: 4px solid gray;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 5em auto;
    padding: 1em 0;
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right-style: dotted;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right : 15px;
}
/* extra refinement */
li:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Questions</li>
    <li>Tags</li>
    <li>Users</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Update css to following

```
ul{ 
    width: 20em;
    border: 4px solid gray;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    margin: 5em auto;
    list-style: None;
    display:flex;
}

li {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 30px 20px 0;
    border-right-style: dotted;
    padding-right : 15px;
}
```

For reference - https://jsfiddle.net/9qyv03u3/3/

Answer (score 2):

### See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/9qyv03u3/2/)

Remove your `float-left` and use `display:inline-block`

**Changed CSS**

```
ul {
    width: 20em;
    border: 4px solid gray;
    margin: 5em auto;
    list-style: None;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 20px 30px 10px 0;
    border-right-style: dotted;
    padding-right : 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to adjust the top margin of the li.

```
    li {
float: left;
margin: 10px 30px 10px 0;
border-right-style: dotted;
padding-right : 15px;
}
```

Instead of

```
    li {
float: left;
margin: 20px 30px 10px 0;
border-right-style: dotted;
padding-right : 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation I would advise against hard coding your height/width and floating li elements to make them display in one line.  You can use `li { display: inline-block }` to achieve the same effect.

Check out the fiddle I created which achieves the same result with less code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ojqu54bd/

```
ul {
   list-style: none;
   border: solid 4px grey;
   padding:10px;
}

li {
   display: inline-block;
   border-right-style: dotted;
   padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

if so, remove li margin and add `line-height: 30px;` or whatever your ul height is. It will always be vertically centered, but it will also work only in a single line

```css
ul{ 
   width: 20em;
    border: 4px solid gray;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    margin: 5em auto;
   list-style: None;
   height: 30px;
}

li {
float: left;
border-right-style: dotted;
padding-right : 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Questions</li>
  <li>Tags</li>
  <li>Users</li>
</ul>
```